# How to update listview items every item added

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to update my listview during every new item add to my arraylist during progress dialog showing this is my code

```
    public class Load extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(SearchList.this);
        progress.setMessage("loading....");
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do tracks loading process here, don't update UI directly here
        // because there is different mechanism for it

        //FlowableBookViewer.webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){var txt = window.getSelection();window.name= txt;window.cpjs.sendToAndroid(window.name);})()");

        for (int i = 0; i < Globals.currenHtmlList.size(); i++) {
            try {
                String pageText = FunctionsClass
                        .readTextFromHtml(Globals.currenHtmlList.get(i));
                if (pageText.toLowerCase().contains(
                        Globals.SelectedText.toLowerCase())) {
                    String pagename = new File(
                            Globals.currenHtmlList.get(i)).getName();
                    SearchItem sitem = new SearchItem();
                    sitem.setTargetList(Globals.currenHtmlList.get(i));
                    sitem.setPageNumber(i);
                    if (pagename.endsWith("html")) {
                        pagename = pagename.substring(0,
                                pagename.length() - 5);
                    } else if (pagename.endsWith("htm")) {
                        pagename = pagename.substring(0,
                                pagename.length() - 4);
                    } else if (pagename.endsWith("xhtml")) {
                        pagename = pagename.substring(0,
                                pagename.length() - 6);
                    }

                    sitem.setTitleList("Page " + pagename);
                    founded.add(sitem);





                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // write display tracks logic here
        progress.dismiss(); // dismiss dialog
        m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(SearchList.this, R.layout.itemview,
                founded);
        lv.setAdapter(m_adapter);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

in this code the listview items appears after the complete of the for loop which add all the items of sitem object to founded list i want to update listview at every item added to founded .
many thanks

Comment: first of all it's not good to refresh list after added each Item. you can run use UI thread in `doInBackground` and call `m_adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();`, but you need create your adapter before that and make `founded` instance of class

Comment: After adding new item just notify your list adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create the adapter before you call the `AsyncTask`

Move this to your activity/fragment `onCreate` method:

```
m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(SearchList.this, R.layout.itemview,
                    founded);
lv.setAdapter(m_adapter);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

2) After you add an item in your ArrayList call the `onProgressUpdate` from the `AsyncTask`

In your `doInBackground` method add:

```
founded.add(sitem);
publishProgress();
```

3) In the `onProgressUpdate` method call the `notifyDatasetChanged` method from your adapter

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... v) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(v);
    m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You can read more about `notifyDataSetChanged` [here](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html).

Comment: Can you please note me simple code to your idea because i tried but nothing changed. thanks for you help

Comment: Thanks for your help but why after finish search it did not hide progress dialog and it run an exception although i edit onPostExecute by this progress.dismiss();

Comment: @user3764397 `progress.dismiss();` should remain in `onPostExecute`. What kind of exception? stack trace?

Comment: Ok progress.dismiss in onPostExecute. the exception is unforunately,app has stopped

Comment: @user3764397 anything in the Logcat?

Comment: I found that this exception because of the touch during search and progress how can i stop AsyncTask thread and select item from the list? I am very very sorry for my questions.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html Take a look at the part about Canceling a task. This question is answered. If you want to ask anything else please post a new question. thanks